# Index heading style is different

Tags: sectioning, indexing, incompatibility, idxlayout

I have document like this (MWE):

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,final]{book}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\usepackage[initsep=16pt,unbalanced=false]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{index}                             
\newindex{default}{idx}{ind}{First index}              

\begin{document}
        \chapter{First}

        Lorem ipsum \index{Lorem@ipsum} et dolorem.

        End of first chapter.

        \printindex

\end{document}
```

And index header is diferent than other.

It is clear to me, that somehow I can use `idxlayout` (maybe own style file). But I always failed when I tried.

Version (Fedora 20):

```
xelatex -v
XeTeX 3.1415926-2.6-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2014/dev)
kpathsea version 6.2.0dev
Copyright 2013 SIL International and Jonathan Kew.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 50.1.2; using 50.1.2
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.8; using 1.2.8
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.5.0; using 2.5.0
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.2.2; using 1.2.2
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 0.9.24; using 0.9.24
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.11.0; using 2.11.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.3; using 1.6.3
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.3
```

Comment: not relevant to the present question, but when you have a space both before and after an `\index{...}` term, (la)tex will *not* compress these spaces into one, so the spacing in the output text will be uneven.  (and remember that an end-of-line is also treated as a space for this purpose.)

Answer (score 3):

As stated in section 2.3 of the `idxlayout` documentation, the `index` package must be loaded before `idxlayout`. With the correct load order, the index heading will be formatted like other (unnumbered) top-level sectioning headings (in your MWE: chapters).